# Parsing data in GCM message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my Android application I use GCM. I receive the message but without data.

I send this json to a GCM server:

```
{
    "data": {
        "data.senderName": "Marco Minerva",
        "data.gcm.collapse_key": "chiave_collassata",
        "data.activityId": "42",
        "data.senderId": "12",
        "data.message": "Hai ricevuto una notifica",
        "data.peerProfileImageUrl": null,
        "data.landingPage": "MainActivity",
        "data.isCorporate": false
    },
    "collapse_key": "chiave_collassata"
}
```

and in `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` I have tried all of these and none works, all variables are NULL:

```
String message = extras.getString("msg");
String data = extras.getString("data");
String m = extras.getString("message");

String m1 = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
String m2 = intent.getStringExtra("data");
String m3 = intent.getStringExtra("message");

String senderName = intent.getExtras().getString("data.senderName");
String dm = intent.getExtras().getString("data.message");

String jsonString = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String senderName = bundle.getString( "data.senderName" );
```

Or if I'm reading it wrong try :

```
Log.d( "message", bundle.toString() );
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
try
{
    Object data = bundle.get( "data" );
    Log.d( "data", data.toString() );
}
catch( Exception e )
{
    Log.e( "exception", e.getMessage() );
}
```

This should show you the structure and check your log cat.

Answer (score 0):

you can get properties,for example:

```
String message = data.getString("message");
    String  title= data.getString("title");
    String subtitle = data.getString("subtitle");
    String ticketText = data.getString("ticketText");
    String largeIcon= data.getString("largeIcon");
    String smallIcon = data.getString("smallIcon");
```